# Intellij IDEA JavaFX Scene Builder different resolution to the rest of the application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I have [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ2ti.jpg) with the JavaFX Scene Builder. It works as intended but the resolution seems to be lower than the rest of the application.

Intellij IDEA did update recently to the 2018 version and thats when the issue started. I have tried downgrading to the previous version but the issue is still there.

Is there a way that I can revert the settings for Scene Builder or is there a setting that I have missed? Can't find anything about it online.

TIA

Comment: Try to reinstall the scenebuilder plugin and you also can try to delete the flag `disable rescale on high DPI` on the execute ICON of the IDE.

Comment: I don't have that exact option as I'm on Win10 but I checked "Override high DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by: System" and the scene builder is desired resolution but the rest of the application is a bit off now. I was only using the integrated Scene Builder. A friend put me on to the Gluon external Scene Builder so will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Please see the comment at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190669 for the workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190669).

Current workaround is to add `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options.

Comment: Thank you. For everyone else running into the Problem: I also had to restart IDEA but now it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this is a `scaling issue`, follow the bellow steps to fix it:

1. right click on the `IntelliJ.exe` file.
2. select **Properties** | **Compatibility**.
3. check the **Compatibility mode** check box and select the **Windows 8** from the drop list.
4. click **Change high DPI settings**.
5. check the **Program DPI** check box.
6. check the **High DPI scaling override** check box and select the **System (Enhanced)** from the drop list.
7. restart the ide.